# What is $\lim\limits_{k \to 0}{f(k) = 2 + k^{\frac{3}{2}}\cos {\frac{1}{k^2}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Just want to check this one:

I got:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{k \to 0}{f(k) = 2} \;+\; \lim_{k \to 0}{k^{\frac{3}{2}}\cos {\frac{1}{k^2}}}$$

Since $\lim\limits_{k \to 0}\cos{\frac{1}{k^2}} = 0$, using the squeeze theorem, I have $\lim\limits_{k \to 0} k^{\frac{3}{2}}\cos{\frac{1}{k^2}} = 0$.

So
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{k \to 0}f(k) &= 2 + \lim_{k \to 0}k^{\frac{3}{2}}\cos\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\\
&= 2 + 0\\
&= 2
\end{align*}$$

Is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but it is false that $\lim\limits_{k\to 0}\cos\frac{1}{k^2}=0$. That limit does not exist: we can find $k$ arbitrarily close to $0$ where the cosine is equal to $0$, to $1$, or to $-1$. It *is* true that $\lim\limits_{k\to 0}k^{3/2}\cos(1/k^2)=0$, and this can be shown using the Squeeze Theorem, but the limit of the cosine alone does not exist.

Comment: @mathstudent Arturo is right (listen to the master). The limit of $cos\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$ does not exist. http://snipurl.com/236mdru

Comment: Apart from everything else: It is absolutely forbidden to use the letter $k$ for a continuous variable.

Answer (score 6):

Almost. Since $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow 0^+} k^{3/2}=0$ (note the one-sided limit) and since $-1\le \cos(x)\le1$ for all $x$, it follows from the Squeeze Theorem  that $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow 0^+} \bigl[\,k^{3/2}\cos(1/k^2)\,\bigr]=0$.

Thus, $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow 0^+} \bigl[2+k^{3/2}\cos(1/k^2)\,\bigr]=2+0=2$.

Comment: but the 2 part at the front? Wouldn't that be 2 + 0 = 2, altogether?

Comment: @mathstudent Yes, I just added that.